# how exactly is the math tag used in Elm?

Tags: mathjax, elm, mathml

Here's just a generic div with some nonsense math in it.   Does not render properly

```
div [] [ math [] [text "$\\int_a^b \frac{2}{3}$"]
```

and here's what comes out

```
<math>$\int_a^b \frac{2}{3}$</math>
```

so I am not understanding how [`math`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html#math) works in Elm.  This is looking like [mathML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML)

For the time being, I would think it easier to make a [mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) call than to learn (or create) a new markup language and write pure mathML.  Here's what it should look like

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <msubsup>
    <mo>&#x222B;<!-- ∫ --></mo>
    <mi>a</mi>
    <mi>b</mi>
  </msubsup>
  <mfrac>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <mn>3</mn>
  </mfrac>
</math>
```

Elm has no `mfrac` tag, but I'd be glad to write in my own!  This set of tags is being used on the web with growing freqency, but may not have been adopted by Elm-Lang itself just yet.

---

Elm does expose `node` where you can define your own tag of any kind.

```
node
    :  String
    -> List (Attribute msg)
    -> List (Html msg)
    -> Html msg
```

This indicated a potential solution.  Didn't lead anywhere though:

```
node "math" [] [ node "mo" [] [ text "&#x222B;"] ]
```

Answer (score 2):

MathML is [only supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=mathml) in Safari and Firefox, so using `Html.node` for producing MathML is not a good cross-browser solution.

You have to use a polyfill for other browsers, such as [KaTeX](https://github.com/khan/katex/releases) or [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).

KaTeX is known to be faster than MathJax and there is an integration for Elm already.

[bsouthga/elm-katex](https://github.com/bsouthga/elm-katex) module allows you to use LaTeX to output mathematical formulas in Elm. Use [elm-github-install](https://github.com/gdotdesign/elm-github-install) to install it for your project.

Have in mind that you will also need the CSS from [KaTeX](https://github.com/khan/katex/releases)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `Html.node` to do anything html supports.

```
view model =
  math []
    [ node "msup" []
      [ node "mi" [] [ text "x" ]
      , node "mn" [] [ text "2" ]
      ]
    ]
```

You may want to to define math constructs instead of
 using `node` everywhere.